Query Azure Devops Test Results via oData connection
We are using an Azure DevOps cloud instance to manage our Test Cases.  All of the manual testing is conducted in ADO.
We have a need to build a PowerBI report to visualize Test Case Execution summary.  I have gotten pretty far with the oData connection but there is one link that I am missing.
I cannot figure out how to join Test Points and Test Runs or Test Results.
These are all the records I am querying:

Test Cases - https://analytics.dev.azure.com//_odata/v4.0-preview/WorkItems?$filter=((WorkItemType eq 'Test Case')
Test Points - https://analytics.dev.azure.com//_odata/v4.0-preview/TestPoints
Tests -  https://analytics.dev.azure.com//_odata/v4.0-preview/tests
Test Runs -  https://analytics.dev.azure.com//_odata/v4.0-preview/testruns
Test Result -  https://analytics.dev.azure.com//_odata/v4.0-preview/testresults

I can join Test Cases and Test Points using TestCases.WorkItemId = TestPoints.TestCaseId.
I can also join Tests and Test Results using Tests.TestSK = TestResults.TestSK.  Test Results and Test Runs can be joined using TestRunSK.
What I need to understand is how do I join Test Points and Test Results/Runs.  This is needed so I can see the various Results/Runs of a Test Point.
why is there is no "Test Case ID" on Test Results or Test Runs?


You may have to also pull in a reference to TestCaseReference. You can then use the TestPointId to get the TestCaseReferenceId, which can be used to get the correct Test record to do the other joins you mentioned.

Hi PandaMagus.   Can you clarify a bit more...where do I pull TestCaseReference ID from?

@user2924101 I'll have to double check a cloud instance, but an on-prem instance I have access to has a TestCaseReference table. I'm assuming there is an equivalent that can be queried using an odata query. That table appears to be the join between the two data sets you're looking for. So in psuedo SQL, it might look something like:
select * from TestPoints tp join TestCaseReference tcr on tcr.TestPointId = tp.TestPointId join Tests t on t.TestCaseRefId = tcr.TestCaseRefId join TestResults tr on tr.TestSK = t.TestSK;
I'll see what I can do about converting it to odata on Monday

@user2924101 Ah... I see that the TestCaseReference data doesn't appear to be visible to odata queries. :( I'm trying to see if there are possible ways to do this with the TestPointHistorySnapshot or TestResultsDaily data sets, but they're still loading into my PowerBI instance.
As a bandaid, could you join on the Test Cases Title to Tests TestName? I think for manual tests those might be the same? I know that won't work for any tests with duplicate names, but might be better than nothing?

Thank you for continuing to check.  I will try using Title but given the number of test cases we have, it probably wont work.  Its surprisingly that such an important lookup table isnt exposed
